# How do I add an unique argument when adding onclick events during a loop?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is add a unique `onclick` on each button using parameters so I can identify each of the buttons when they are clicked, using function parameters.

```
function createProducts() {
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length;i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.className = "products";
        li.onclick = "purchase(" + i + ")";
        li.innerHTML = products[i][0] + "<span class=\"price\"> Klikk/s: " + products[i][1] + " Pris: " + products[i][2] + "</span>";
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
    }
}

function purchase(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

I've tried

```
li.onclick = purchase(i);
```

And

```
li.onclick = "purchase(" + i + ")";
```

But none of these work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the `li` creation loop:

```
li.onclick = purchase;
li.dataset.index = i;
```

In the `purchase` event:

```
function purchase(id) {
    var index = this.dataset.index;
}
```

More about data attributes(`dataset`) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: @timzand As TJ explained, you store the *index*  in loop-time to an attribute called data attribute on your element. It will be available to reading anywhere, anytime in your element. So, inside the click event function you just read it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of choices. You can create a variable for your handler to close over that doesn't change (like `i` does). You can do that in your case with [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
function createProducts() {
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length;i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.className = "products";
        li.onclick = purchase.bind(li, i); // <====
        li.innerHTML = products[i][0] + "<span class=\"price\"> Klikk/s: " + products[i][1] + " Pris: " + products[i][2] + "</span>";
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

`Function#bind` returns a function that, when called, will call the original with a specific `this` value (we're setting it to the element reference) and any arguments you passed `bind` (in our case, `i`). Since the value that gets bound is the value of `i` when we call `bind`, not when the click occurs, it doesn't change like `i` would.

Alternately, you can store the `id` on the element itself as an attribute, and then use that in your handler:

```
function createProducts() {
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length;i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.className = "products";
        li.setAttribute("data-id", i);
        li.onclick = purchase;
        li.innerHTML = products[i][0] + "<span class=\"price\"> Klikk/s: " + products[i][1] + " Pris: " + products[i][2] + "</span>";
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
    }
}

function purchase() {
    // Use this.getAttribute("data-id") here to get the value
}
```

Note that in both cases, we're using real function references, not strings. You can use functions with the `onXyz` properties on elements, or of course use the standard `addEventListener` (or `attachEvent` on old IE).

Comment: I like the `bind` suggestion.